# Bitwise operators and for loop

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to understand the bitwise and the shift operators. I wrote a simple code to show me the bits in a short type.

```
class Shift {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        short b = 16384;

        for (int t = 32768; t > 0; t = t / 2) {
            if ((b&t) != 0) System.out.print("1 ");
            else System.out.print ("0 ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        b = (short)(b + 2);
        for (long t = 2147483648L; t > 0; t = t / 2) {
            if ((b&t) != 0) System.out.print ("1 ");
            else System.out.print ("0 ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

And the output is:

```
C:\>java Shift
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
```

I used with the second for an AND with a short (16 bits) and a long (64 bits) and the output is 32-bits.
I don't understand why the output of the second for is 32-bits.
Thank you.

Comment: How did you come up with `2147483648L` and `32768`?

Comment: If you want to work with bits, do not use decimal literals like `32768` or `2147483648L`. Use `0x8000` or `1 << 14` instead. And use `>>` and `<<` instead of `/2` and `*2`. That'll make the intents clearer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You start your loop with `long t = 2147483648L`, which is 2^31. Therefore your loop has 32 iterations and prints 32 bits.

If you wish to display more bits, start the loop with `long t = 0x4000000000000000L;` (which is equivalent to the binary number starting with 01 and ending with 62 0s).

Comment: The correct starting number would be `long t = Long.MIN_VALUE` (which is actually the number with highest bit set).

Comment: @TagirValeev I agree that Long.MAX_VALUE was wrong, but `Long.MIN_VALUE` is also wrong, since `t > 0` will be false from the start, and `t = t/2` won't work either.

Comment: Yes, it should be like `for(long t = Long.MIN_VALUE; t != 0; t >>>= 1)`